# word problem involving interest rate for investment

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

A cash rich household can ear 10% interest per annum from a savings account, with interest paid once a year. Estimate the financial benefit in pounds over a 3 year period if this household invests in roof and cavity wall insulation. Compared with  investing in a savings  account

The question doest tell me what the investment, is so not sure how to start.

Comment: but the question doesnt say double glazing? It only says roof and cavity wall insulation, so it would be £225 + £375. But I dont get the right answer or anywhere close.

Comment: Getting the wrong answer is not the reason to ask how to do a problem from scratch. Maybe you just made a mistake. Please post your work so we can determine whether you made a simple error or if your approach is incorrect.

Comment: What is the answer?

Answer (score 1):

How much do the improvements cost?  If they put that much in a savings account, how much do they have at the end of $3$ years?  Compare that with the savings over $3$ years.  You can argue whether the first year savings should draw $2$ years' interest.

Comment: The investment costs 225 + 375 = £600, and than calculating 10% interest on this is in 3 years is £2184.6 . where as investing in the roof anf wall cavaity insulation saves $840 over three years,

Comment: No, $10\%$ interest for three years should only add a little over $30\%$ where you are more than tripling.

Comment: if its 10% per annum, and I start with £600, by the end of  year one i will have 660 year 2 10% of 660 = 726 and year 3 is 798.6

Comment: But you don’t add those together. You have 798.6 at the end of 3 years. You would only add them if you invested another 600 each year